# How do I convert an array to a JSON object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to ROR, I have some seed data stored in my database table and a YAML file. I have been loading the yaml file and converting it into a JSON which I parsed and displayed to the client.

Something like this.

**controller.rb**

```
def template_library
    @template_library_all= YAML::load(File.open('./db/seeds/template_library.yml'))
end
```

In my view I did

**reports.html.slim**

```
javascript:
  var templateLibraryJSON = #{@template_library_all.to_json.html_safe};
```

So now I want to use the model to get the data from the database and parse it into JSON, instead of using a static file.

What I have done so far.

```
def query_library
@template_library_JSON = TemplateLibrary.all.map { |i| ['file_name:' , [i.file_name]]}
end
```

**in my view**

```
javascript:
  var templateJSON = #{@template_library_JSON.to_json.html_safe};
```

this returns me a JSON which looks like a JSON array.

```
[["file_name:", ["daily_data_count_report"]]]
```

Do I have to construct the JSON object ?

Comment: Can you try `var templateJSON = #{j @template_library_JSON.to_json}` (j is an alias for escape_javascript) ? And if not working, this: `var templateJSON = #{j @template_library_JSON.as_json}` (using as_json instead of to_json)

Comment: That didn't work, for some reason ruby adds escaping quotes and it breaks the view. But my concern was that I was not getting a valid JSON object which I can use in my JS

Comment: Hi, please edit your question and add en example of a JSON you want as an output, it is really not clear what you are trying to achieve. Do you want it to be [{"file_name": "daily_data_count_report"}]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your #map call returns an array of arrays, not a hash. Try this instead:

`@template_library_JSON = TemplateLibrary.all.map { |i| { :file_name => i.file_name } }`